# How do I summarize levels from different columns in r

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a table (df) with categorical variables as factors with different levels

| A_ID | B_ID | C_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valid number | valid number | invalid number |
| valid number | valid number | invalid number |
| invalid number | invalid number | too shot |
| too shot | too shot | too shot |
| valid number | too long | too shot |
| too long | too long | valid number |
| invalid number | valid number | too long |
| too long | invalid number | too long |
| too short | too short | valid number |
| too short | valid number | too long |
| too long | invalid number | too long |
| valid number | invalid number | valid number |

I want to summarize each column based on their number of levels, for example, I want to count the number of times  each level occurred in each column, the result should look like the table below

| Variable | Count_valid | Count_Invalid | Count_Short | Count_Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_ID | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| B_ID | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| C_ID | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I have tried using apply fuction:

```
t(sapply(names(df), function(x) 
  c(count_Valid=count(df[x])== "valid value", 
    count_Invalid=count(df[x]) == "invalid value", 
    count_Short=count(df[x] == "too short", 
    count_Long=count(df[x] == "too long")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)    
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% count(name, value) %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = value, values_from = n) %>% 
   select('Variable' = name, 'Count_valid' = `valid number`, 'Count_Invalid' = `invalid number`, 'Count_Short' = `too short`, 'Count_long' = `too long`)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Variable Count_valid Count_Invalid Count_Short Count_long
  <chr>          <int>         <int>       <int>      <int>
1 A_ID               4             2           3          3
2 B_ID               4             4           2          2
3 C_ID               3             2           3          4
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   A_ID           B_ID           C_ID          
   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
 1 valid number   valid number   invalid number
 2 valid number   valid number   invalid number
 3 invalid number invalid number too short     
 4 too short      too short      too short     
 5 valid number   too long       too short     
 6 too long       too long       valid number  
 7 invalid number valid number   too long      
 8 too long       invalid number too long      
 9 too short      too short      valid number  
10 too short      valid number   too long      
11 too long       invalid number too long      
12 valid number   invalid number valid number
```